# Best Practice for Having a Base Project and Multiple Similar Sub-projects

Tags: project-management, reusability, git-fork

I have been writing an E-shop project for a customer and now I have signed a new similar contract with another customer. I was wondering what would be the best practice to continue the first project while staring the second so that the reusability is at maximum?

One way would be to change the first project to read all menu items, slider pictures, ... from the database so that I can deliver the same project to both customers with different databases. The benefit of this approach is that I have to manage only one project, but it leads me to gradually write a CMS, which is a time-consuming task.

The other solution would be to use Git. For example, I would fork the base project into two different projects. If the functionality I am writing is the base one, then I would push it into the base project; otherwise, I push it into the appropriate forked project.

Which one is a better approach in your opinion? Or you guys have any better idea?

Cheers,
Habib

Comment: Have you tried using feature flags?

Comment: https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

Comment: Here's the actual pattern introduced on Fowler's blog. You can find more material online. Feature flags help you enable/disable features for special customers, customer segments, environments, and even different times of the day.

Comment: Thanks for the help. BTW, I am coding using Laravel. I have searched and found some packages for the feature flagging in Laravel as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found some solutions that I would like to share with you guys. Let's divide differences into 2 big categories of data differences and code differences:

**Differences in data**

If the database in each project is different (e.g., the product has some features in one project and some other features in another project), then the best solution is to use NoSQLs such as MongoDB. In the first place, NoSQLs are designated to support databases that don't have well-defined data structures, and you don't know what features you may add to each entity at present or in the future. It completely applies to my scenario that each shop may have a different data structure. However, since my project is based on Laravel and it does not have built-in support for MongoDB, I have decided to design some key-value tables that haven't been so bad so far.

**Differences in the code**

Regarding differences in the code, I would definitely suggest branches in Git and other functionalities provided by Git repositories such as Gitlab repository mirroring. Each feature has a different branch in my code, and I can provide each customer with different functionalities by merging those branches I want to deliver to the customer.

All in all, you may take as much business logic as you can into the database since changing it in the future is more straightforward. On the other hand, you'd better keep themes in the code because every customer likes a different theme, and changing them in the code is easier than taking them to the database.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that need to be considered.

- First of all, This project as you said has the capability to be sold more. So, you must think about how much is possible to make it dynamic via Configuration files, Hooks & Plugins to make the modification to the functionalities of the project through that. I know you have considered this already.
- Second,  Using a Core Repository and different forks for customization. (It's a great idea but needs proper discipline, workflow and manpower to make sure everything is fine-tuned and works properly )
- It's highly recommended to make your application cloud-native and provide proper UAT/QAT Environment for test before launching on the production, And also implementing Test cases to be checked within the Git and CI/CD pipelines in order to prevent issues in the merge process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about what you want, but if you want to develop an enterprise project that contains many features such as wallet, tracking, payment,... I think you can implement each service as a microservice and integrate all of them.
About git, I think it's better just for handling the source code and you had better use git module for handling microservice and just using branches for developing process